# how to store & get file from database using codelgniter php & my sql

Tags: php

i can store the file into database but can't get / display the file stored in database

the file is stored in the database but can't display from the database

i am using following code

```
<?php

class file_upload extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        echo "  <head>
        <title>Upload Image To Database</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <!-- (A) HTML FILE UPLOAD FORM -->
        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
          <input type='file' name='upload' accept='.png,.gif,.jpg,.webp' required/>
          <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload Image'/>
        </form>";

        if (isset($_FILES['upload'])) 
        {
          $imgname=$_FILES["upload"]["name"];
          $data["img_name"]=$_FILES['upload']['name'];
          $data["img_data"]=file_get_contents($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"]);
          $this->db->insert('images',$data);
          $data=$this->db->query('select * from images where img_name="$imgname"');
          foreach ($data->result() as $row)
          {
            print_r($row->img_data);
            echo "<img src='data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64, ";
            echo "base64_encode($row->img_data)";
            echo "height=100 width=100>";
          }

        }
    }  
}

?>
```

Comment: You should not store the file itself in the database but the path it is stored under on your filesystem and maybe its static url.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. You're `base64_encode` cannot be executed in a string interpolation like that. You can't run functions inside a string interpolation at all. This should work.

```
<?php

class file_upload extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        echo "  <head>
        <title>Upload Image To Database</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <!-- (A) HTML FILE UPLOAD FORM -->
        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
          <input type='file' name='upload' accept='.png,.gif,.jpg,.webp' required/>
          <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload Image'/>
        </form>";

        if (isset($_FILES['upload'])) 
        {
          $imgname=$_FILES["upload"]["name"];
          $data["img_name"]=$_FILES['upload']['name'];
          $data["img_data"]=file_get_contents($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"]);
          $this->db->insert('images',$data);
          $data=$this->db->query('select * from images where img_name="$imgname"');
          foreach ($data->result() as $row)
          {
            print_r($row->img_data);
            echo "<img src='data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64, ";
            echo base64_encode($row->img_data);
            echo "'height=100 width=100>";
          }

        }
    }  
}

?>
```

Also, since you've hard coded `jpg`, if you've uploaded anything other than that it may not show in the image tag correctly.

Overall it would be better to store the image in a directory somewhere and then store, in your database, information about the image. type, width, height, location, etc.

Also, since you're using CI I recommend checkout out their handy functions for handling files.
Specifically https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/incomingrequest.html?highlight=file%20upload#uploaded-files
and
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/filesystem_helper.html

Happy coding!

Comment: i want to must store file in database

Comment: @RenishBatadaSocialmedia No problem, the above code should work for you. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

some quotation (" " / ' ') problem so use following code

```
<?php

class file_upload extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        echo "  <head>
        <title>Upload Image To Database</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <!-- (A) HTML FILE UPLOAD FORM -->
        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
          <input type='file' name='upload' accept='.png,.gif,.jpg,.webp' required/>
          <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload Image'/>
        </form>";

        if (isset($_FILES['upload'])) 
        {
          $data["img"]=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"]));
          $this->db->insert('img',$data);

            $data=$this->db->query("select * from img");
            
              foreach ($data->result_array() as $row)
              {
                echo $row['id'];
?>
              <img src="data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64, <?php echo base64_encode($row['img']); ?> " height=200 width=200> </img>
<?php
              }
        }      
    }  
}

?>
```